# Branch points+cuts, $(z+k)^{1/2}$ and $(z+k)^{-1/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Do the complex functions $f(z)=(z+k)^{1/2}$ and $f(z)=(z+k)^{-1/2}$ have the same branch points? If so, why? Also, would this mean that we can take the same branch cut for both functions?
Thanks.

Comment: I should state that k is a constant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume we use the standard determination for the argument. (I.e in $(-\pi,\pi]$)

Then $f(z) = \sqrt{z+k}$ is not holomorphic when $(z+k)$ is negative, i.e. if $z \in (-\infty,-k]$. This is the cut you want.
Moreover the cut for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z+k}}$ is also $(-\infty,-k]$ for the same same reason (holomorphy of the square root). In addition you can't divide by $0$, i.e. in $z=-k$, but this point is already removed in the cut.

So yes, the cuts are the same.

Comment: My apologies! Please see the edit.

Comment: Ok i've edited my post.